# Python suds error Server raised fault: 'Session expired'

Tags: php, python, soap, suds

I'm trying to write a python script to call SOAP PHP API methods. I've gotten it to go as far as successfully getting the required tokens but when I actually try to call any method I get an error.

Here is the code I'm using, with certain data redacted

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
import logging
from suds import WebFault
import suds


username = "apiUserAccount"
password = "apiPassword"
keyword = "computerNameImSearchingFor"

logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

url = 'url/to/service.php?wsdl'  # wsdl api url
tns = 'url/to/api/'  # target name space from php
#fixing broken schema
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add(tns)

client = Client(url, plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])  # calling api
print client

#This calls the request for an authentication token
auth_token = client.service.auth_request_api(username, password)
username = "myUserName"
password = "myPassword"
user_login = client.service.auth_request_user(auth_token, username, password)
#this works
print "api token: " + api_token
#this also works
print "login token: " + login

#This doesn't work...
try:
    print client.service.search_in_namehost(user_login, keyword)
except suds.WebFault as detail:
    print detail
```

The error gets thrown in the `search_in_namehost` method call, here is the output, I've removed some of it for space sake

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( SERVICENAME ) tns="address/to/server/api/"
   Prefixes (2)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      ns1 = "http://address/to/server/api/"
   Ports (1):
      (SERVICENAME_serviceSoap)
         Methods (20):
            auth_request_api(xs:string username, xs:string password, )
            auth_request_user(xs:string auth_token, xs:string username, xs:string password, )
            search_in_namehost(xs:string login_token, xs:string keyword, )
         Types (50):
            ns0:Array
            ns0:ENTITIES
            ns0:ENTITY
            ns0:ID
            ns0:IDREF
            ns0:IDREFS

api token: alphaNumericApiToken
login token: alphaNumericApiToken
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/python/script.py", line 42, in <module>
    result = client.service.incidents_list(user_login)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 643, in send
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/client.py", line 678, in succeeded
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 154, in get_reply
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 498, in returned_types
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 441, in bodypart_types
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(array, http://internalserver/servicename/api/, )'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I created a `test.php` file to call the methods using the documentation, I do get the data I want. Here is the php code:

```
<?php
include("soapclient.php");

$tech_username = "api_user";
$tech_password = "apipassword";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$keyword = "computername";
$client = new SERVICE_serviceSoapClient();
$api_token = $client->auth_request_api($tech_username, $tech_password);
$user_token = $client->auth_request_user($api_token, $username, $password);
print_r($client->search_in_namehost($user_token, $keyword));
?>
```

And this is what I get when I run php `test.php` in the terminal

`test.php` outputs this in the terminal

```
localhost:Documents username$ sudo php phpinfo.php 
Array
(  
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => computername
            [section] => Hosts
            [incident] => Test Incident - DO NOT DELETE
            [url] => https://urlToIncident
        )

)
```

Given I can successfully get data, I know the issue is something with suds but I have minimal experience with both PHP and using suds and the documentation for both suds and the API I'm working with aren't as robust as I'd like. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

**UPDATE**
Sorry if I didn't edit this right, I'm new to actually posting on here but I've made some progress...

So a co-worker familiar with SOAP but not python suggested I change the way I pass parameters to the method calls. So I did this and edited the code above accordingly as well as the output with the new error I'm getting. At this point I'm sure python is getting the information from the method but can't necessarily handle how it is presented.

As I mentioned above what the output in the terminal looks like when you call test.php, I timed how long it took to return that compared to how long it took to return this new error once the script got to that method call and they are roughly the same. Before, I was getting the session expired error almost immediately. So now I suppose the issue is getting python to handle the data it gets correctly which I'm now working on trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from a coworker he found the issue to be with the WSDL I was using. Suds was looking for a type of array that didn't exist. Once I changed all instances of that type in the WSDL everything worked as normal. Unfortunately I can't post the WSDL but I'm happy to answer questions as best I can if anyone happens to have any.